# Java array list size issue

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm currently working on a project for class but struggling with a bit of coding relating to 
`ArrayList`s. It is as yet unfinished code; however, when I'm working on the `enrollstudent`
method I'm having an issue comparing the length of an `ArrayList` to the variable `amountstudents`.

Below is a copy of the code for the full class. There is another seperate class related but I don't think it's relevant here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Course {

    int amountstudents;
    String coursename;
    String level;
    ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<String>();
    String tutor;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Course(int MaxCapacity) {
        MaxCapacity = amountstudents;
        tutor = "Not set yet";
        coursename = "Not set yet";
        level = "Not set yet";
    }

    public void enrollstudent(String addstudent) {
        if(students.size > amountstudents) {
            System.out.println("Unfortunately the class is already full so you can not be enrolled at this time");
        }
        else {
            students.add(Student.fname);
        }
    }

    public void courselevel() {
        System.out.println("Please enter course level");
        level=in.next();
    }

    public void coursetitle() {
    }
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having with this? The only issue I see is `size` should be `size()` since it is a method of the `ArrayList` class.

Comment: When you say you have an issue with the comparison, what is the issue exactly? Is there an error message?

Comment: Hi cheers for the response, the issue was not having () after size. My regards.

Comment: is this right: MaxCapacity = amountstudents; shouldn't it be the other way around

Comment: Hi - yep was pointed out to me that was the wrong way around. My regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `students.size()`, not `students.size`.

Also, there's another error:

It should be `students.add(addstudent)`, not `students.add(Student.fname)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's `students.size()`, since `students` is an `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `students.size()`. `size` is a method on List types, not a property (like `length` is on arrays).

Also, in the constructor, you have this reversed:

```
MaxCapacity = amountstudents;
```

it should be:

```
amountstudents = MaxCapacity;
```